# Integral of the exponential function $\exp(-c_1x-c_2x^2-c_3|x-\mu|^\beta)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, improper-integrals

Is it possible to find a solution to
$$\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-c_1x-c_2x^2-c_3|x-\mu|^\beta)dx$$
where all parameters are positive?

I also accept good approximations to an analytical form.

**Added:** The result for $\beta=1$ and $x>\mu$ is

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \exp\Big[{\frac{(\text{$c_1$}+\text{$c_3$})^2+4c_2\text{$c_3$} \mu}{4 \text{$c_2$}}\Big] }\text{erfc}\left(\frac{\text{$c_1$}+\text{$c_3$}}{2 \sqrt{\text{$c_2$}}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\text{$c_2$}}}$$

And the result for $\beta=2$ is

$$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \exp\Big[{\frac{\text{$c_1$}^2-4 \text{$c_1$} \text{$c_3$} \mu -4 \text{$c_2$} \text{$c_3$} \mu ^2}{4 (\text{$c_2$}+\text{$c_3$})}}\Big] \text{erfc}\left(\frac{\text{$c_1$}-2 \text{$c_3$} \mu }{2 \sqrt{\text{$c_2$}+\text{$c_3$}}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{\text{$c_2$}+\text{$c_3$}}}$$

They are similar in some sense.

Comment: As far as I know $\int_{0}^\infty \exp(-c_1x-c_2x^2-c_3x^3)\,dx$ does not exist.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Convergence of the integral looks fine to me.  The integrand is continuous, and goes to zero very rapidly at $+\infty$.  I see no reason to expect a closed form for the OP, though.

Comment: @GEdgar. For sure, there is no problem to compute it. Do you have any idea for a possible closed form ? Cheers :-)

Comment: For $F(c_1,c_2,c_3) = \int_0^\infty \exp(-c_1x-c_2x^2-c^3x^3)dx$, $c_1,c_2,c_3 \ge 0$, Maple shows closed forms for $F(0,c_2,c_3)$ and $F(c_1,0,c_3)$.  (In terms of things like Whittaker M and Weber E.)

Comment: @GEdgar For $\beta=1$ and $\beta=2$ as well. Could one at least do a very good analytical approximation. It would also suffice.

Comment: @GEdgar the term with $|x-\mu|^\beta$ is also not scary. The integral can be found in closed form as it is the CDF  of generalized Gaussian as found here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnorm/vignettes/gnormUse.html